# DocuSign redirect after signIn

Tags: docusignapi

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedDocuSign
This code gives auth and redirects to https://demo.docusign.net/Member/Home.aspx but I want  redirect to Envelope view

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to re-direct without any issues using the `http://foo.com` URL you have specified, so there must be something else going on with your code.  Have you seen the DocuSign API Walkthroughs located here?

```
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs
```

They demonstrate 9 common use-cases of the DocuSign API and if you look at the bottom 3 you'll see that they are all focused on **Embedding** functionality.  Using the 8th walkthrough, titled *Embedded Signing* I was able to get this working with the following requests:

1) **Create an Envelope from a Template with one embedded recipient**

```
{
"accountId": "221765",
"emailSubject": "DocuSign API Call - Embedded Signing",
"emailBlurb": "This comes from PHP",
"templateId": "9347C7AF-7EEE................",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "email": "fakeemail@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "clientUserId": "1001"
    }
],
"status": "sent"
}
```

2)  **Get The Embedded Signing View**

```
{
"returnUrl": "http://foo.com",
"authenticationMethod": "email",
"email": "fakeemail@gmail.com",
"userName": "John Doe",
"clientUserId": "1001"
}
```

If I sign the envelope or decline, cancel, etc. it sure enough re-directs me to http://foo.com.  You can set the clientUserId to whatever value you'd like but just remember to use the same value for that recipient when requesting the recipient view in the second part.